# Writing efficient code. Handling large number of rows in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

So the code I am working on does the following:

test.php:

1. Queries the mysql table (entities) for all entities with date_next < NOW() and date_end > NOW()
2. Computes a new date_next
3. Checks to see if this new date_next is less than 24 hours away
4. If not, it continues to the next entity
5. If so, it queries another table called "table2" and selects all entries where table2.entity_id = entities.id
6. It uses the ids it gets from table2 to send a batch request to a third party server. 500 ids are sent to the third party server in each request.

My question is, if there are over 50,000 entries in the entities table (#1), I get the error  "too much memory". I am guessing that I should try to restrict the result set from #1. So I was thinking of putting a LIMIT on the result set each time. So the script test.php runs multiple times a day and each time it LIMITs the query from #1 to only retrieve 20,000 results each time. But I am not sure if that is the right way to limit the result set.

For #6, there is a network latency. I tried using curl multi function to send multiple requests at a time, but each request is already big since for each request, 500 ids are being sent. I am not quite sure what the pro/cons of using curl multi function is here ...

Are there ways that I have not considered to make the job above more efficient?
I was considering the following:
- Reverse proxies
- OS tuning of number of TCP packets
- Using compiler cache
- Increasing PHP memory limit. Not sure what other configurations I should be setting though.
- Running test.php multiple times so as to limit the result set. Each time, only processing 20,000 or less records.

Comment: Have you considered filtering in your query and joining the tables?

Comment: code, code, code then show us your code. most db admins would laugh at calling 50k large

Comment: It sounds like steps 1 through 5 could be done in one query.

Comment: What is the computation done to get date_next?

Comment: In addition to the code (or even pseudo-code) for next date computation, can you show some sample data of what you have, and what you are EXPECTING to get back.

Answer (score 1):

Query for steps 1 - 5

```
SELECT table2.entity_id FROM table2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT table1.id FROM table1 
WHERE table1.date_next < NOW() and table2.date_end > NOW() 
HAVING DATEDIFF(date_next_function(date_next), NOW()) > 1) as table3 
   ON table2.entity_id = table3.id
```

I am using the having clause to filter out any rows which are 24 hours away using the computation of the date_next_function